# Implementing search with Haystack and Solr issues

Tags: django, search, solr, django-haystack

I'm trying to implement search to my django based website.

While following the [tutorial](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v1.2.7/tutorial.html) I found this:

> If you’re using the Solr backend, you have an extra step. Solr’s
>   configuration is XML-based, so you’ll need to manually regenerate the
>   schema. You should `run ./manage.py build_solr_schema` first, drop the
>   XML output in your Solr’s schema.xml file and restart your Solr
>   server.

**First**, I don't know where to put my schema.xml, after some resarch I figured I'd create a folder inside my project to put it: `myprojectname/solr/schema.xml`. Is that right?

**Second**, how do I restart Solr?

**UPDATE**

I downloaded Solr,unzipped it and I put the schema.xml generated inside `example/solr/conf`

then I start solr `java -jar start.jar`

but when I try to build the index :
   `./manage.py rebuild_index`

I get :

```
WARNING: This will irreparably remove EVERYTHING from your search index.
Your choices after this are to restore from backups or rebuild via the `rebuild_index` command.
Are you sure you wish to continue? [y/N] y

Removing all documents from your index because you said so.
All documents removed.
Indexing 1 News.
Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: None]
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int    name="QTime">4</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=news.news.2]   unknown field 'django_id'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst></response>
Indexing 1 entries.

Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: None]
<response><lst name="responseHeader"><int name="status">400</int><int name="QTime">17</int></lst><lst name="error"><str name="msg">ERROR: [doc=zinnia.entry.2] unknown field 'django_id'</str><int name="code">400</int></lst></response>
```

I verified my schema.xml ,and I do have :

```
<field name="django_ct" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="django_id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false" />
```

<sub>**P.S.**
I'm using Django 1.2 and Haystack 1.2.7</sub>

Comment: important note: Haystack is not solr. it has adapters to interface with solr. You still need to have solr installed somewhere. http://websolr.com/ is pretty easy to get up and going with or install solr locally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solr server needs to have a copy of your schema.xml not django. I usually keep a copy of the schema.xml in my django project for version control, but solr can't find it there.

Is you solr server local? Are you using a hosted or remote Solr service? I develop locally then use websolr b/c i dont want to configure solr for production.

### For local dev on OSX

I'm assuming this is local development on OSX and that you have homebrew installed (assumptions - give me more info if this isnt the case):

```
brew install solr
```

This is going to install Solr at someplace like: `/usr/local/Cellar/solr/...`

Note: When im developing locally, I like to use fabric for running deployment and some startup tasks.

So in my fabfile.py I have a fabric command to copy my schema.xml into the proper file and start the solr server (I just run `fab solr` at the cmd line)

```
def solr() :
    # build a new updated schema.xml (changes to indexes/models may require this so always do it for local testing)
    local('python manage.py build_solr_schema > schema.xml')
    # copy the schema.xml into the proper directory
    local('cp schema.xml /usr/local/Cellar/solr/3.6.0/libexec/example/solr/conf/schema.xml')
    # start the solr server
    local('cd /usr/local/Cellar/solr/3.6.0/libexec/example && java -jar start.jar')
```

Note: you can run these commands on the command line if you dont use fabric

Comment: yes local developpement under ubuntu, already installed , pip install pysolr, i still can't find solr location,is there a cmd or something to get me the install path

Comment: pysolr is not a solr server, its a python wrapper for communication with a solr server. I dont do too much ubuntu, check this out: https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot/wiki/Configure-Solr-on-Ubuntu,-the-quickest-way or http://www.shayanderson.com/linux/install-solr-on-ubuntu-1104-server.htm

Comment: ok so I installed it, put the shema in colr/conf then started it  , but when I rebuild the index I get : Failed to add documents to Solr: [Reason: None]<html><head><title>Error 404...

Comment: add the full stack trace to your question? I can't debug without seeing it. Although a 404 error would indicate that it can't find your sorl server. did you put the correct address to your solr server in the proper setting var? ex: `HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL    = 'http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr'`

Comment: yes I have : `HAYSTACK_SOLR_URL = 'http://localhost:8983/solr'` . updated my question,thanks

Comment: your solr server is not looking at the correct schema.xml try stopping solr, replacing the schema.xml (with root priv?) and then restarting. I had this issue for a while. django_id is defined by haystack not in solr, solr's default xml doesn't have references to django_id resulting in problems.

Comment: also note, that solr requires a restart every time you change the schema.xml.

Comment: I already did that several times,just to make sure I'm doing it right,the schema.xml goes into my solr unzipped folder inside example/solr/conf ?  to REstart I use the command java -jar start.jar ? then I rebuild then I got the error again..I'm starting to pull my hair !!!

Comment: i am leaning towards your solr not being installed configured properly. try a service that is managed: http://www.opensolr.com/pricing the free tier, upload your schema and see if it works then.

Comment: @MadeehaAmeer, Ok so I had a similar issue. My problem was that v2.x does not create good schema.xml. downgrade to 1.2.7, generate solr schema, upgrade to 2.x and use the old schema and you should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, the rebuild task failed. For me the solution was:

1. Build a new schema.xml and place it in the corresponding folder
2. Restart Solr
3. rebuild the index without problems